# CSS :after not working

Tags: css, opacity

I'm trying to make background image transparent only, I know that I can make it by adding opacity at CSS :after. But it seems my code editing script or css has a problem and I don't know why.

I'm trying to check what's wrong with my code. I was expecting to see red-colored background with this code, but I can't see any red color

```
<head>
<style type="text/css"> #chattingBox:after { background-color: red !important;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chattingBox" style="overflow: scroll; height: 150px; border: 1px solid black; background: url("/images/large/5.png") center center / 100px no-repeat;"></div>
</body>
```

I can see red color when I write CSS as '#chattingBox { background...'(without :after) so I guess it's problem about :after but I don't have any idea to get through this.

If :after problem can be solved, I can set opacity also, does anybody knows why :after is not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That’s because your `:after` pseudo element is empty. If you add some content such as:

```
#chattingBox:after {
    content: "\A0";
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Then you will see something. The `\A0` is the code for a non-break space (equivalent to HTML `&nbsp;`, but any content will do.

Generally, `:after` and `:before` are incomplete without `content` of some sort.